# Относительное позиционирование внутри окружности path SVG

Tags: svg

Нужно разместить изображение внутри path относительно его края. Пробовал использовать pattern, но он имеет квадратный viewBox. Вся задача состоит в том, зная координаты объекта, я мог вставить его в окружность по x и y.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1534 1226.6" version="1.1" >
<g id="surface1">
<path style="fill: url(#img336095580);
                            stroke-width: 20px;
                            stroke-linecap: round;
                            stroke-linejoin: round;
                            stroke: #0a0a0a;
                            stroke-opacity: 1;
                            stroke-miterlimit: 10;" d="M 1072.839844 1223.748437 L 325.839844 1223.748437 L 322.878906 1223.721094 L 319.929688 1223.6 L 317.011719 1223.420312 L 314.109375 1223.158594 L 311.230469 1222.838281 L 308.378906 1222.439844 L 305.539063 1221.971094 L 302.738281 1221.428125 L 299.960938 1220.830469 L 297.210938 1220.158594 L 294.480469 1219.420312 L 291.78125 1218.619531 L 289.121094 1217.760156 L 286.480469 1216.830469 L 283.878906 1215.838281 L 281.300781 1214.779687 L 278.761719 1213.670312 L 276.261719 1212.498437 L 273.78125 1211.271875 L 271.351563 1209.978906 L 268.949219 1208.63125 L 266.589844 1207.228906 L 264.261719 1205.771875 L 261.980469 1204.248437 L 259.730469 1202.689844 L 257.53125 1201.06875 L 255.371094 1199.400781 L 253.25 1197.678125 L 251.171875 1195.908594 L 249.140625 1194.080469 L 247.148438 1192.221094 L 245.210938 1190.299219 L 243.320313 1188.338281 L 241.46875 1186.330469 L 239.671875 1184.279687 L 237.929688 1182.178125 L 236.230469 1180.041406 L 234.578125 1177.861719 L 232.988281 1175.63125 L 231.449219 1173.369531 L 229.960938 1171.06875 L 228.53125 1168.728906 L 227.160156 1166.35 L 225.839844 1163.928125 L 224.578125 1161.478906 L 223.371094 1158.998437 L 222.230469 1156.478906 L 221.148438 1153.920312 L 220.121094 1151.338281 L 219.160156 1148.721094 L 218.269531 1146.06875 L 217.429688 1143.400781 L 216.660156 1140.689844 L 215.960938 1137.959375 L 215.320313 1135.201562 L 214.75 1132.408594 L 214.238281 1129.6 L 213.808594 1126.760156 L 213.441406 1123.900781 L 213.148438 1121.021875 L 212.929688 1118.119531 L 212.78125 1115.189844 L 212.699219 1112.248437 L 212.699219 1109.291406 L 215.96875 828.310937 L 215.96875 825.908594 L 215.921875 823.529687 L 215.800781 821.158594 L 215.640625 818.799219 L 215.410156 816.459375 L 215.140625 814.13125 L 214.808594 811.81875 L 214.429688 809.529687 L 213.988281 807.248437 L 213.511719 804.998437 L 212.96875 802.760156 L 212.390625 800.541406 L 211.75 798.338281 L 211.070313 796.158594 L 210.328125 793.998437 L 209.550781 791.869531 L 208.71875 789.760156 L 207.851563 787.670312 L 206.921875 785.611719 L 205.960938 783.56875 L 204.941406 781.549219 L 203.890625 779.56875 L 202.789063 777.611719 L 201.640625 775.678125 L 200.460938 773.771875 L 199.230469 771.900781 L 197.960938 770.049219 L 196.648438 768.240625 L 195.300781 766.451562 L 193.910156 764.701562 L 192.480469 762.978906 L 191.011719 761.291406 L 189.511719 759.639062 L 187.96875 758.021875 L 186.390625 756.428125 L 184.769531 754.889062 L 183.121094 753.369531 L 181.441406 751.900781 L 179.71875 750.459375 L 177.96875 749.060937 L 176.179688 747.701562 L 174.359375 746.38125 L 172.511719 745.1 L 170.628906 743.861719 L 168.71875 742.658594 L 166.78125 741.498437 L 164.800781 740.389062 L 162.800781 739.31875 L 160.769531 738.299219 L 158.71875 737.31875 L 156.628906 736.38125 L 154.519531 735.498437 L 152.390625 734.658594 L 150.230469 733.861719 L 148.039063 733.119531 L 145.828125 732.420312 L 143.601563 731.779687 L 141.339844 731.178125 L 139.058594 730.639062 L 136.761719 730.139062 L 134.441406 729.701562 L 132.101563 729.310937 L 129.738281 728.978906 L 127.359375 728.701562 L 53.820313 720.951562 L 52.449219 720.791406 L 51.101563 720.6 L 49.761719 720.369531 L 48.429688 720.119531 L 47.109375 719.838281 L 45.808594 719.529687 L 44.511719 719.178125 L 43.238281 718.810937 L 41.96875 718.408594 L 40.71875 717.990625 L 39.480469 717.529687 L 38.261719 717.049219 L 35.859375 715.998437 L 33.519531 714.85 L 31.238281 713.6 L 29.039063 712.248437 L 26.898438 710.799219 L 24.839844 709.260156 L 22.851563 707.639062 L 20.941406 705.920312 L 19.109375 704.119531 L 17.371094 702.248437 L 15.71875 700.291406 L 14.148438 698.260156 L 12.679688 696.158594 L 11.300781 693.990625 L 10.019531 691.760156 L 8.839844 689.471094 L 7.761719 687.119531 L 6.789063 684.709375 L 5.929688 682.248437 L 5.179688 679.740625 L 4.851563 678.471094 L 4.550781 677.189844 L 4.269531 675.889062 L 4.03125 674.588281 L 3.808594 673.271875 L 3.628906 671.951562 L 3.480469 670.619531 L 3.351563 669.271875 L 3.261719 667.920312 L 3.199219 666.56875 L 3.179688 665.201562 L 3.179688 663.830469 L 12.050781 99.330469 L 12.121094 96.63125 L 12.269531 93.959375 L 12.488281 91.299219 L 12.769531 88.670312 L 13.121094 86.049219 L 13.539063 83.471094 L 14.019531 80.908594 L 14.558594 78.369531 L 15.171875 75.861719 L 15.839844 73.369531 L 16.578125 70.920312 L 17.371094 68.490625 L 18.21875 66.1 L 19.128906 63.728906 L 20.101563 61.389062 L 21.128906 59.088281 L 22.210938 56.81875 L 23.351563 54.580469 L 24.539063 52.38125 L 25.789063 50.209375 L 27.078125 48.080469 L 28.429688 45.990625 L 29.828125 43.928125 L 31.28125 41.920312 L 32.78125 39.939844 L 34.320313 37.998437 L 35.910156 36.1 L 37.550781 34.248437 L 39.238281 32.428125 L 40.960938 30.670312 L 42.738281 28.939844 L 44.550781 27.260156 L 46.398438 25.63125 L 48.300781 24.041406 L 50.230469 22.498437 L 52.210938 21.010156 L 54.21875 19.56875 L 56.269531 18.178125 L 58.351563 16.838281 L 60.46875 15.549219 L 62.628906 14.310937 L 64.820313 13.13125 L 67.039063 11.998437 L 69.289063 10.928125 L 71.570313 9.908594 L 73.878906 8.951562 L 76.21875 8.041406 L 78.589844 7.201562 L 80.988281 6.408594 L 83.410156 5.678125 L 85.859375 5.021875 L 88.328125 4.408594 L 90.820313 3.869531 L 93.339844 3.389062 L 95.878906 2.971094 L 98.441406 2.619531 L 101.019531 2.338281 L 103.609375 2.119531 L 106.230469 1.971094 L 108.859375 1.88125 L 111.511719 1.869531 L 114.179688 1.928125 L 116.851563 2.049219 L 119.550781 2.248437 L 137.46875 3.81875 L 155.789063 5.459375 L 193.511719 8.939844 L 232.5 12.63125 L 272.53125 16.459375 L 313.390625 20.38125 L 354.871094 24.310937 L 396.761719 28.189844 L 417.78125 30.1 L 438.828125 31.971094 L 459.878906 33.799219 L 480.890625 35.580469 L 501.839844 37.299219 L 522.699219 38.959375 L 543.449219 40.541406 L 564.058594 42.041406 L 584.511719 43.451562 L 604.761719 44.760156 L 624.789063 45.971094 L 644.578125 47.060937 L 664.089844 48.029687 L 683.300781 48.88125 L 692.789063 49.248437 L 702.191406 49.580469 L 711.5 49.88125 L 720.71875 50.150781 L 729.839844 50.369531 L 738.871094 50.560937 L 747.789063 50.701562 L 756.609375 50.810937 L 1357.980469 56.56875 L 1360.660156 56.63125 L 1363.328125 56.740625 L 1365.988281 56.920312 L 1368.621094 57.158594 L 1371.238281 57.459375 L 1373.839844 57.810937 L 1376.429688 58.228906 L 1378.988281 58.701562 L 1381.53125 59.228906 L 1384.050781 59.810937 L 1386.550781 60.451562 L 1389.03125 61.150781 L 1391.488281 61.889062 L 1393.921875 62.701562 L 1396.320313 63.549219 L 1398.699219 64.459375 L 1401.058594 65.420312 L 1403.378906 66.428125 L 1405.679688 67.490625 L 1407.960938 68.6 L 1410.199219 69.760156 L 1412.410156 70.959375 L 1414.589844 72.221094 L 1416.75 73.521875 L 1418.871094 74.869531 L 1420.960938 76.271875 L 1423.011719 77.709375 L 1425.03125 79.189844 L 1427.019531 80.721094 L 1428.96875 82.291406 L 1430.890625 83.908594 L 1432.761719 85.560937 L 1434.609375 87.260156 L 1436.410156 88.998437 L 1438.171875 90.779687 L 1439.898438 92.6 L 1441.589844 94.451562 L 1443.230469 96.35 L 1444.828125 98.279687 L 1446.390625 100.248437 L 1447.910156 102.260156 L 1449.378906 104.299219 L 1450.808594 106.38125 L 1452.199219 108.490625 L 1453.539063 110.63125 L 1454.828125 112.810937 L 1456.070313 115.021875 L 1457.269531 117.271875 L 1458.421875 119.541406 L 1459.519531 121.838281 L 1460.558594 124.178125 L 1461.558594 126.541406 L 1462.511719 128.939844 L 1463.398438 131.361719 L 1464.238281 133.799219 L 1465.03125 136.279687 L 1465.769531 138.779687 L 1466.441406 141.299219 L 1467.070313 143.861719 L 1467.628906 146.428125 L 1468.140625 149.029687 L 1468.589844 151.650781 L 1468.980469 154.299219 L 1469.320313 156.959375 L 1530.820313 699.240625 L 1531.070313 701.791406 L 1531.25 704.338281 L 1531.351563 706.869531 L 1531.378906 709.38125 L 1531.339844 711.88125 L 1531.21875 714.361719 L 1531.039063 716.81875 L 1530.78125 719.260156 L 1530.460938 721.670312 L 1530.070313 724.06875 L 1529.609375 726.439844 L 1529.089844 728.791406 L 1528.5 731.111719 L 1527.851563 733.408594 L 1527.140625 735.678125 L 1526.359375 737.920312 L 1525.519531 740.13125 L 1524.628906 742.310937 L 1523.679688 744.459375 L 1522.660156 746.580469 L 1521.601563 748.670312 L 1520.46875 750.721094 L 1519.300781 752.740625 L 1518.058594 754.721094 L 1516.78125 756.658594 L 1515.441406 758.56875 L 1514.058594 760.439844 L 1512.621094 762.260156 L 1511.140625 764.049219 L 1509.601563 765.791406 L 1508.03125 767.490625 L 1506.398438 769.150781 L 1504.730469 770.760156 L 1503.019531 772.330469 L 1501.261719 773.85 L 1499.46875 775.31875 L 1497.628906 776.740625 L 1495.75 778.111719 L 1493.839844 779.439844 L 1491.878906 780.701562 L 1489.890625 781.920312 L 1487.871094 783.080469 L 1485.808594 784.189844 L 1483.710938 785.248437 L 1481.589844 786.240625 L 1479.429688 787.178125 L 1477.238281 788.060937 L 1475.019531 788.88125 L 1472.769531 789.63125 L 1470.5 790.330469 L 1468.199219 790.971094 L 1465.871094 791.541406 L 1463.519531 792.041406 L 1461.140625 792.478906 L 1458.75 792.85 L 1456.328125 793.158594 L 1453.890625 793.400781 L 1451.429688 793.560937 L 1448.949219 793.658594 L 1446.449219 793.678125 L 1443.941406 793.63125 L 1441.410156 793.510156 L 1438.859375 793.31875 L 1436.308594 793.041406 L 1285.441406 774.799219 L 1283.101563 774.541406 L 1280.761719 774.361719 L 1278.441406 774.228906 L 1276.128906 774.170312 L 1273.828125 774.170312 L 1271.550781 774.228906 L 1269.269531 774.361719 L 1267.019531 774.541406 L 1264.78125 774.779687 L 1262.558594 775.080469 L 1260.351563 775.439844 L 1258.171875 775.85 L 1256 776.31875 L 1253.851563 776.85 L 1251.730469 777.428125 L 1249.621094 778.060937 L 1247.539063 778.748437 L 1245.480469 779.490625 L 1243.449219 780.279687 L 1241.441406 781.13125 L 1239.460938 782.021875 L 1237.5 782.959375 L 1235.578125 783.951562 L 1233.679688 784.990625 L 1231.808594 786.080469 L 1229.96875 787.209375 L 1228.160156 788.389062 L 1226.378906 789.619531 L 1224.640625 790.889062 L 1222.929688 792.201562 L 1221.25 793.549219 L 1219.609375 794.951562 L 1218.011719 796.389062 L 1216.441406 797.869531 L 1214.910156 799.389062 L 1213.421875 800.951562 L 1211.96875 802.541406 L 1210.550781 804.178125 L 1209.179688 805.85 L 1207.851563 807.560937 L 1206.570313 809.299219 L 1205.320313 811.080469 L 1204.128906 812.889062 L 1202.96875 814.740625 L 1201.859375 816.619531 L 1200.800781 818.529687 L 1199.789063 820.471094 L 1198.828125 822.439844 L 1197.910156 824.439844 L 1197.050781 826.471094 L 1196.230469 828.529687 L 1195.46875 830.611719 L 1194.761719 832.721094 L 1194.109375 834.861719 L 1193.5 837.029687 L 1192.960938 839.209375 L 1192.46875 841.428125 L 1192.03125 843.658594 L 1191.660156 845.920312 L 1191.339844 848.189844 L 1191.078125 850.490625 L 1190.890625 852.810937 L 1190.75 855.150781 L 1190.671875 857.510156 L 1185.96875 1112.689844 L 1185.878906 1115.56875 L 1185.71875 1118.428125 L 1185.480469 1121.271875 L 1185.179688 1124.088281 L 1184.808594 1126.889062 L 1184.378906 1129.658594 L 1183.871094 1132.408594 L 1183.300781 1135.139062 L 1182.671875 1137.85 L 1181.96875 1140.529687 L 1181.210938 1143.178125 L 1180.378906 1145.810937 L 1179.488281 1148.408594 L 1178.550781 1150.971094 L 1177.539063 1153.510156 L 1176.46875 1156.021875 L 1175.339844 1158.498437 L 1174.160156 1160.951562 L 1172.921875 1163.361719 L 1171.628906 1165.740625 L 1170.28125 1168.080469 L 1168.878906 1170.389062 L 1167.421875 1172.658594 L 1165.910156 1174.889062 L 1164.351563 1177.088281 L 1162.738281 1179.240625 L 1161.078125 1181.361719 L 1159.371094 1183.439844 L 1157.621094 1185.471094 L 1155.808594 1187.459375 L 1153.960938 1189.408594 L 1152.070313 1191.310937 L 1150.128906 1193.170312 L 1148.148438 1194.990625 L 1146.128906 1196.748437 L 1144.058594 1198.471094 L 1141.949219 1200.139062 L 1139.808594 1201.760156 L 1137.621094 1203.330469 L 1135.398438 1204.85 L 1133.140625 1206.31875 L 1130.839844 1207.728906 L 1128.5 1209.088281 L 1126.140625 1210.400781 L 1123.738281 1211.650781 L 1121.300781 1212.838281 L 1118.828125 1213.978906 L 1116.339844 1215.060937 L 1113.808594 1216.080469 L 1111.25 1217.041406 L 1108.660156 1217.939844 L 1106.050781 1218.779687 L 1103.410156 1219.560937 L 1100.738281 1220.271875 L 1098.050781 1220.920312 L 1095.328125 1221.510156 L 1092.589844 1222.029687 L 1089.828125 1222.478906 L 1087.050781 1222.861719 L 1084.238281 1223.178125 L 1081.421875 1223.428125 L 1078.578125 1223.611719 L 1075.71875 1223.721094 L 1072.839844 1223.748437 " transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,1226.6)" filter="url(#dropshadow336095580)"></path>


</g>
<defs>
                                    <filter id="dropshadow336095580" height="130%">
                                      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="10"></feGaussianBlur> 
                                      <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"></feOffset>
                                      <feComponentTransfer>
                                        <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.5"></feFuncA>
                                      </feComponentTransfer>
                                      <feMerge> 
                                        <feMergeNode></feMergeNode>
                                        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode> 
                                      </feMerge>
                                    </filter>
                                  </defs></svg>
```